# Off the shelf external ESD protection for USB port

Tags: usb, esd

I'm looking for an off-the-shelf external ESD protection for USB port. I live in dry climate and I zap my keyboard or mouse quite often when I forget to touch grounded surface first. I already killed one KVM switch this way and I would like to protect the replacement from early death. Quick google search yielded no useful results. My plan B is to use a cheap USB hub as ESD protection or weakest link, but I would prefer an in-line gadget specifically designed for this job.

**EDIT**

As expected, my question was found off-topic. If you analyse it carefully, you will find that I'm asking primarily about existence of a useful but rare electronic device. Try finding it yourself without reading my answer and it will become obvious to you. I'm not necessarily seeking a brand or place to purchase recommendation. I always hoped that StackExchange editors would comprehend border line scenarios like this one better than a deep neural network, which is itching to take over their duties.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic for this site. Personally, I'd just put my keyboard and mouse on a grounded anti-static mat.

Comment: @Finbarr I have an anti-static mat, but when I touch a mouse first with my hand above the mat, I'm still discharging through grounded USB bus. As far as _shopping question_ goes, I don't need a specific brand recommendation, if that's prohibited. Technical name of the gadget would suffice.

Comment: I always find that my wrist hits the desk before my fingers touch the mouse or keyboard, hence the suggestion.

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists. I think you'd be in the situation of spinning your own board with a socket, plug and protection devices. Or you can get sockets with protection built in which makes the board just a special socket and a plug. To be honest a cheap sacrificial hub is probably the best bet.

Comment: @Andrew I searched in vain for ESD protected USB socket - I'm finding ESD protection ICs only.

Comment: Wurth Electronics part number 8492121

Comment: Just touch the nearest chassis ground before you touch the keyboard

Comment: @laptop2d Of course, that's the program I'm running, except of occasional memory error, once a month or so, when I forget to ground my hand and zap my mouse!

Comment: Regarding your new edit: There's nothing "borderline" about a consumer electronics shopping question just because the product is rare, and your question is not improved with a rant. Take it to [meta](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you really care about the issue.

Comment: @PaulJurczak The shopping rules are stackexchange rules, and they come down from the top. If you pose the question of how could I build a circuit or device to accomplish ESD control on USB then that would be acceptable.

Comment: @laptop2d If you are convinced that my question is harmful to StackExchange, you have the power to delete it. I thank everyone who helped me find the part I was looking for. Too bad anyone with the same problem in the future will not be able to benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a clue from Andrew, I found in-line USB EMC adapter pictured below:

[image]

I hope [link to part's datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Wurth%20Electronics%20PDFs/829999STICK.pdf) doesn't contravene rules of this forum.